need assistance for llama-index modules importion
need assistance for llama-index modules importion
I'm running into some import issues with Llama.index in my Python code. I'm trying to use several modules, including LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, SimpleDirectoryReader, etc., but I'm getting an error specifically for GPTVectorStoreIndex:
 File "d:\l\zira_0.0.2\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from llama_index import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'GPTVectorStoreIndex' from 'llama_index' (unknown location)

from llama_index import (
    GPTVectorStoreIndex,
    LLMPredictor,
    PromptHelper,
    ServiceContext,
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    StorageContext,
    load_index_from_storage,
)
from llama_index.llm_predictor.mock import MockLLMPredictor
from llama_index.nodes.parser import SimpleNodeParser 
from llama_index.response.formatting import SimpleOutputFormatter

I've checked the documentation and it seems like GPTVectorStoreIndex should be part of Llama.index, but I can't import it. I'm using pip to manage my dependencies, so I'm not sure why it's not available.
Here are some things I've tried so far:

Double-checked import path: I've verified that the spelling and path are correct (from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex).

Restarted development environment: I've restarted my IDE to ensure the updated library is loaded.


These haven't resolved the issue.
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this import error and use GPTVectorStoreIndex with Llama.index?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

GPTVectorStoreIndex was renamed to VectorStoreIndex, according to LlamaIndex official documentation. So you should use VectorStoreIndex instead (here are the usage guidelines).
